# Union by new category using R and sf

Tags: r, union, sf

I'd like to create a new shapefile or a new geometry variable that allows me to plot borders around regions in R. I'm using the `sf` and mapping with `tmap`. Basically, I'm adding a character vector to an `sf` object and would like to make the character vector the new/preferred mapping border.

Here is an example of my approach, which doesn't do what I'd like. I can't tell that it does anything.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

## use North Carolina example 
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc_new.region <- nc %>% ## add new region variable
    mutate(new.region  = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), nrow(.),replace = T))

nc_union <- nc_new.region %>% 
    group_by(new.region) %>% # group by the new character vector
    mutate(new_geometry = st_union(geometry)) # union on the geometry variable


# map with tmap package
tm_shape(nc_union)+
    tm_borders()
```

[image]

PS I posted this at SO as I wasn't sure where to put it.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/57625471/820534